# rails has_many through scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-many-through

I am linking a `Company` and `User` model through an `Association` table:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations
  has_many :companies, :through => :associations

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations
  has_many :users, :through => :associations
```

In my Association I have an boolean column named `active`:

```
create_table "associations", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "active"
```

In my company controller I am trying to get a company array that includes the fact that the user has been activated or not for the company.

I managed to use a scope, but this only achieved to filter if the company is active or not, and not the association:

```
@companiesactive = @user.companies.by_status(true)
```

Looking to get the result of something like:

```
@companiesuseractive = @user.companies.where("association.active", true)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: got it
@companies = @user.companies.where("associations.active = ?", 1)